# Passing additional parameters with a form submission to a controller with ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an Edit view that allows my user to update the technical information about a vehicle. When the edit is carried out I want to pass a Customer Number and a Vehicle Number to the controller so that I can make an audit log entry against the customer and vehicle to record the changes.

I have this code in my controller:

GET:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, int? AuditLogID, int? ErrorLogID, int CustomerNo, int VehicleNo)
```

POST:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, VehicleAssetTechnicalInformation technicalInformation, int CustomerNo, int VehicleNo)
```

The CustomerNo and VehicleNo should be required - an update should not be able to proceed without these details as everything must be audited.

In my Edit.cshtml view I have this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", 
    "VehicleAssetTechnicalInformation", 
    FormMethod.Post, 
    new { CustomerNo = (int)ViewBag.CompanyID, 
        VehicleNo = (int)ViewBag.VehicleID }))
```

Inside my View I even show the ViewBag.CompanyID and ViewBag.VehicleID to the user so I know they exist when the view is loaded.

However, when I submit the form I get the following:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'CustomerNo' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32, VehicleAssetTechnicalInformation, Int32, Int32)
```

For some reason the CustomerNo and VehicleNo are not being submitted as attributes with the form.

What can I do to make sure these values are passed along?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware you can't bind single parameters *after* you have defined a model parameter (all parameters are assumed to belong to the model). My advice would be to merge all your parameters into a single view model e.g.

```
public class VehicleSubmissionViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerNo { get; set; }
    public int VehicleNo { get; set; }
    public VehicleAssetTechnicalInformation TechnicalInfo { get; set; }
}
...
public ActionResult Edit(VehicleSubmissionViewModel viewModel)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @James. I have defined my ViewModel like this.


`public class VehicleAssetTechnicalInformationViewModel : VehicleAssetTechnicalInformation
    {
        public int UnifiedDatabaseCompanyId { get; set; }
        public int UnifiedDatabaseVehicleId { get; set; }
    }`

Is this method valid too?

Comment: @MikeRouse As a nested view model? Yes this should be fine.